# Evaluating multivariate functions with some arguments fixed

Tags: matlab

I have an anonymous multivariate function. Is it possible to find the value of the function by fixing one of the values?

Here is what I would like to happen:

```
>> f = @(a, b) a + b;
>> f(1, b) 

ans =

    1 + b
```

I understand that the input I gave above is syntactically invalid, since variables must contain values. Is there a way I can accomplish this through another Matlab tool?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can accomplish this. Either, you get the [symbolic toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/), and declare `b` as a symbolic variable before evaluating `f`, or you create a new anonymous function like this:

```
g = @(b)f(1,b);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to output the result? I'd like to see g as 1 + b, not its anonymous function definition.

Comment: @Zach Rattner: Not that I know of (unless you went the symbolic toolbox route).